# How do you describe $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a brain which only have a notion of sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, mathematical-physics

As a low-level theoretical physics student, my hands are always dirty with abstract mathematics, and whenever I get the chance I try to dive deep. Recently I had an *Advanced Mathematical Physics* course following Nakahara. And while dwelling over the concepts, I find it really pleasing to start from the bare minimum and start building structure. However, sometimes it appears that people along the way throw in concepts that are ment to be understood or met later. E.g., I don't understand how do we speak of charting a circle given by relation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ while we still know nothing about coordinates?
On the same footing, how do you describe $\mathbb{R}^n$ just knowing that it's a set of n-tuples?

EDIT: My questions come from a place of not understanding. So I am asking implicitly for showing me where I'm looking at things wrong. So please tell me how should I look at these abstract creatures

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence? It's a set of n-tuples of real numbers

Comment: The steps for showing that $\Bbb R^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb  R$ are really easy. The first thing is that we can add two $n$-tuples in a very natural way. So the answer is, we describe $\Bbb R^n$ as a vector space by very basic linear algebra.

Comment: @JonatanGarcia I mean the most you can do, is to say that I "pack" my elements in my set into n-tuples. I know I'm being vague. most probably my question doesn't make sense

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's a good way to build it up. But still "rule of interaction between members - addition" doesn't yield to notions like Open balls and distances... we will meet the idea of Metric down the road. but still, as if we borrow it, for the time being, we use it to define open balls. I'm so insecure about discussing my crooked perception of math, but still :)

Comment: Is your question *How can we define the plane without first defining cartesian products?*?  If so, the answer is: you can't.  But all texts have to assume some material as foundational.  In the one you're reading, cartesian products are understood.

Comment: *How do you describe $\mathbb{R}^n$ just knowing that it's a set of n-tuples?*
You need more structures, like inner products, norms, and metrics, which can all be formally defined in set theory.
With these additional structures you can now talk about orthogonality, length, and distance.
On second thought, can you?
Isn't it too artificial to base one's understanding of orthogonality, etc. in such narrow minded terms.
Inner products are relative.
There are infinitely many ways to define inner products in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is the dot product really that canonical?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes that is my question. thank you! I'm not stuck on the aforementioned source in particular, but the whole concept. I'm struggling to build math along just with the basic notions. As in the case where you begin with propositional logic, and based on that you define relations and logical operations. I fail to see how a structure is built just using minimum knowledge. No one tells the motivation.

Comment: And the doubt goes on.
You could end up doubting how we could use second order logic and set theory before we have an appropriate logic system with enough abundance to begin discussing second order logic and set theory.

Comment: @SimonEatwell I find the beauty in the abstraction where you agree to define, let's say orthogonality, in the most condensed and weird way but still at the end of the day, it covers all the applications. I'm actually ok with abstraction. where I struggle I guess are the junction points between different ideas. Thanks for your time

Comment: None of the formalism from some first principles (axioms) really matters on its own.
It only matters if it captures the essential aspects of some notion you want to discuss.
Once you settle on a specific formalism and all the package that comes with it, you can work purely in that context.
It might prove useful of addressing junctions between different ideas.
When it doesn't, choose another set of formalism, which requires a reconsideration on what is more fundamental.

Comment: $n$-tuples of real numbers is a means to an end, i.e., all your previous intuitions about space.
How do you describe yourself as a collection of atoms occupying spacetime?
In this question, *you* are what is important, and not the formalism.
Dwelling on the formalism easily looses the sense of what is important.

Comment: @SimonEatwell Man your last comment below my mind! Indeed, how do I describe myself as a collection of atoms?!!!!
Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{R}^n$ is characterized or defined up to a natural isomorphism by the universal property of products:

To be precise, $\mathbf{R}^n$ is not merely a set, but a set $\mathbf{R}^n$ together with $n$ functions

$$\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n\colon\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$$
with the following universal property: If $X$ is a set and $f_i\colon X\to\mathbf{R}$ are some functions, then there exists exactly one function $f\colon X\to \mathbf{R}^n$ such that $f_i=\pi_i\circ f$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

For $X\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we write $X_i:=\pi_i(X)$ and $(X_1,\ldots,X_n):=X$.

**Definition of addition and scalar multiplication**:

- Consider the product $\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n$ with projections $\Pi_{1,2}\colon\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^n$. By the universal property of $\mathbf{R}^n$ there exists a unique function $A\colon \mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^n$ with the property $\pi_i\circ A=(\pi_i\circ\Pi_1)+(\pi_i\circ\Pi_2)$, i.e.
  $$(X+Y)_i=X_i+Y_i$$
  for all $i$.
- Consider the product $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}^n$ with projections $\Pi_1\colon\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$. By the universal property of $\mathbf{R}^n$ there exists a unique function $M\colon \mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^n$ with the property $\pi_i\circ M=\Pi_1\cdot(\pi_i\circ\Pi_2)$, i.e. $$(\lambda\cdot X)_i=\lambda\cdot X_i$$
  for all $i$.

So far, we have defined a vector space structure.

**Definition of the inner product**:

The standard inner product is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n&\to\mathbf{R}\\
(x,y)&\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\pi_i(x)\cdot\pi_i(y)
\end{align}
The inner product defines a norm and the norm defines a metric, which allows to assign a distance to each pair of points.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Filippo.
Now I ask: Ok you used mapps and a rule called product. I'm fine with that. but still you can't define distance with only these two. it is still not $R^n$ that we'll finally get know. we need to define vectors and charts and orthogonality etc. thus far, we only have a set of n-tuples with rules to interact

Comment: maybe I'm looking over the fact that we are familiar with the ordered set $\mathbb{R}^n$  and we impose (or ask or expect) the elements to follow the inherit the same property? I think at the "Product" level we implicitly accept the idea that "we know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an ordered set, and you can define size and distance" ? Am I right?

Comment: @hamid I have updated the answer.

Comment: Please let me know if something is unclear or if you have any additional questions.

Comment: It's clear as a clean soul. Now I see it better. I'm not formally educated in math so, I'm a retard on the matter. Grazie @Filippo

Comment: @hamid I am glad this was helpful :) Keep wondering about such things!

Comment: By the way, what I explained was just a special case of the product of a family of sets $I\ni i\mapsto X_i$. In this case $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $X_i=\mathbf{R}$ for all $i\in I$.